# reorg a bitcoin transaction

Tags: mining-reward

does anyone here have btc reorg full concept documentation that can be seen online?

also i wonder if a specific block can be reorged?

or all the blocks thats after the transaction must be reorged?

for example the guy who lost 8,999 BTC in 2011.

can the miners help him now to reorg his block to get it back?

or they have to re-un-mining all the blocks they did between 2019 and 2011 to do that successfully ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blockchain is a chain.

Each block is a link in this chain, that depends on the previous link (block) by definition.

If to change block N, all blocks from N until now must be mined again as well.

Moreover, if you want to alter a specific transaction, you are limited to only removing it if you do not hold the key(s) used to sign the transaction. If you wish to perform an alteration that changes where the BTC is sent, you must not only mine the entire section of the chain again, but also hold the private key(s) involved in that transaction to produce an alternative, valid tx.

Comment: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=782.0